# c# selenium click div button

Tags: javascript, selenium

Hello I am unsure how I would execute this div button. I have heard about using javascript but that is beyond me

[image]

any ideas are much appreciated

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: post your code and error message/stack at here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked a simple question, you'll get a simple answer.

```
//div[@class='fav'][contains(., 'favorite')]
```

Comment: It actually throws a access violation when using .click(); on it

Comment: Can I get access to the site via a link?